# Create Multiple/multilevel navigation menu on WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, user-interface, menu, navigation, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to implement a navigation menu same as https://www.santaferelo.com/

On top bar, it has two links as Personal and business which each opens to the pages with the different main menus.

So far I created similar layout using elementor with two buttons as personal and business but can't figure out how do I show which one is active and how do I change the Main menu accordingly.

Kindly provide me with a direction or any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is a lot simpler than I thought.

You can just use a specific plugin to add a conditional menu to the WordPress website and add conditions to display menus.

Eg. Plugin - [Conditional Menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/conditional-menus/)

Still, more suggestions are welcome on how can I do it without using a plugin.

Thank you